# Making a matrix square and padding it with desired value in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In general we could have matrices of arbitrary sizes. For my application it is necessary to have square matrix. Also the dummy entries should have a specified value. I am wondering if there is anything built in numpy?

Or the easiest way of doing it

**EDIT :**

The matrix X is already there and it is not squared. We want to pad the value to make it square. Pad it with the dummy given value. All the original values will stay the same.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

Building upon the answer by LucasB here is a function which will pad an arbitrary matrix `M` with a given value `val` so that it becomes square:

```
def squarify(M,val):
    (a,b)=M.shape
    if a>b:
        padding=((0,0),(0,a-b))
    else:
        padding=((0,b-a),(0,0))
    return numpy.pad(M,padding,mode='constant',constant_values=val)
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Numpy 1.7, there's the [`numpy.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) function. Here's an example:

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(2,3)
>>> np.pad(x, ((0,1), (0,0)), mode='constant', constant_values=42)
array([[  0.20687158,   0.21241617,   0.91913572],
       [  0.35815412,   0.08503839,   0.51852029],
       [ 42.        ,  42.        ,  42.        ]])
```

Answer (score 3):

For a 2D numpy array `m` it’s straightforward to do this by creating a `max(m.shape)` x `max(m.shape)` array of ones `p` and multiplying this by the desired padding value, before setting the slice of `p` corresponding to `m` (i.e. `p[0:m.shape[0], 0:m.shape[1]]`) to be equal to `m`.

This leads to the following function, where the first line deals with the possibility that the input has only one dimension (i.e. is an array rather than a matrix):

```
import numpy as np

def pad_to_square(a, pad_value=0):
  m = a.reshape((a.shape[0], -1))
  padded = pad_value * np.ones(2 * [max(m.shape)], dtype=m.dtype)
  padded[0:m.shape[0], 0:m.shape[1]] = m
  return padded
```

So, for example:

```
>>> r1 = np.random.rand(3, 5)
>>> r1
array([[ 0.85950957,  0.92468279,  0.93643261,  0.82723889,  0.54501699],
       [ 0.05921614,  0.94946809,  0.26500925,  0.02287463,  0.04511802],
       [ 0.99647148,  0.6926722 ,  0.70148198,  0.39861487,  0.86772468]])
>>> pad_to_square(r1, 3)
array([[ 0.85950957,  0.92468279,  0.93643261,  0.82723889,  0.54501699],
       [ 0.05921614,  0.94946809,  0.26500925,  0.02287463,  0.04511802],
       [ 0.99647148,  0.6926722 ,  0.70148198,  0.39861487,  0.86772468],
       [ 3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ],
       [ 3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ,  3.        ]])
```

or

```
>>> r2=np.random.rand(4)
>>> r2
array([ 0.10307689,  0.83912888,  0.13105124,  0.09897586])
>>> pad_to_square(r2, 0)
array([[ 0.10307689,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.83912888,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.13105124,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.09897586,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

etc.