# Elegant way to create empty pandas DataFrame with NaN of type float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I want to create a Pandas DataFrame filled with NaNs. During my research I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784192/creating-an-empty-pandas-dataframe-then-filling-it):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,4),columns=['A'])
```

This code results in a DataFrame filled with NaNs of type "object". So they cannot be used later on for example with the `interpolate()` method. Therefore, I created the DataFrame with this complicated code (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704823/initializing-numpy-matrix-to-something-other-than-zero-or-one)):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dummyarray = np.empty((4,1))
dummyarray[:] = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame(dummyarray)
```

This results in a DataFrame filled with NaN of type "float", so it can be used later on with `interpolate()`. Is there a more elegant way to create the same result?

Comment: I had to put dummyarray = np.empty((4,1)) for me to work

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Simply pass the desired value as first argument, like `0`, `math.inf` or, here, `np.nan`. The constructor then initializes and fills the value array to the size specified by arguments `index` and `columns`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[0, 1, 2, 3], columns=['A', 'B'])

>>> df
    A   B
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN

>>> df.dtypes
A    float64
B    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Works for pd.Series too.  Excellent!

Comment: Replace `np.nan` by `np.full(shape=(4,2),fill_value=np.nan)` save running time! Test for `10000` rows and `10` for example.

Comment: @SayOL: I cannot confirm. `%timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.full(shape=(100_000,26), fill_value=np.nan), index=range(100_000), columns=range(26))` only slightly faster (1.63 ms/loop) compared to its simpler version (1.67 ms) on my machine. Which speedup do you observe with which exact setup?

Answer (score 14):

You could specify the dtype directly when constructing the DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,4),columns=['A'], dtype='float')
>>> df.dtypes
A    float64
dtype: object
```

Specifying the dtype forces Pandas to try creating the DataFrame with that type, rather than trying to infer it.

Answer (score 7):

Hope this can help!

```
 pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index = np.arange(<num_rows>), columns = ['A'])
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this line of code:

```
pdDataFrame = pd.DataFrame([np.nan] * 7)
```

This will create a pandas dataframe of size 7 with NaN of type float:

if you print `pdDataFrame` the output will be:

```
     0
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
```

Also the output for `pdDataFrame.dtypes` is:

```
0    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

For multiple columns you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([nrow, ncol])*np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just pass an empty dictionary with repetition.

```
df= pd.DataFrame([{}]*4, columns=['A'])
```