# Elegant way to create empty daru DataFrame with nil

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, daru

I need to create an empty DataFrame with an specific shape for example [10,10] to store data from other source.

In pandas is straightforward:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(10), columns=range(10))
```

But in ruby using [daru](https://rubygems.org/gems/daru), I'm not sure how to do that.

Related Question: [pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053329/elegant-way-to-create-empty-pandas-dataframe-with-nan-of-type-float)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the names of the vectors in the `:order` option and a range as an index in the `:index` option. The input will be an empty `Array`.

For example:

```
require 'daru'
df = Daru::DataFrame.new([], order: (1..4).to_a, index:(0..10).to_a)
# => 
#<Daru::DataFrame:72941700 @name = 2357edc1-f425-4ae3-aead-5a8b812ecb13 @size = 11>
#                    1          2          3          4 
#         0        nil        nil        nil        nil 
#         1        nil        nil        nil        nil 
#         2        nil        nil        nil        nil 
#         3        nil        nil        nil        nil 
#         4        nil        nil        nil        nil 
#         5        nil        nil        nil        nil 
#         6        nil        nil        nil        nil 
#         7        nil        nil        nil        nil 
#         8        nil        nil        nil        nil 
#         9        nil        nil        nil        nil 
#        10        nil        nil        nil        nil
```