# How do I create an empty pandas DataFrame with different data types assigned to each column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053329/elegant-way-to-create-empty-pandas-dataframe-with-nan-of-type-float) provides an elegant way to create an empty pandas DataFrame of a specified data type.  And if you specify np.nan values when you initialize it, the data type is set to float:

```
df_training_outputs = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=index, columns=column_names)
```

But I want to create an empty DataFrame with different data types in each column.  It seems the dtype keyword argument will only accept one.

Background: I am writing a script that generates data incrementally and so I need somewhere to store it during the execution of the script.  I thought an empty data frame (large enough to take all the expected data) would be the best way to do this.  This must be a fairly common tasks so if someone has a better way please advise.

Comment: May be it will be effective to use a number of Series for each column and concatenate them when a DataFrame is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can create an empty dataframe with columns of different types is by providing an empty numpy array with a correct structured dtype:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.empty(0, dtype=[('a', 'u4'), ('b', 'S20'), ('c', 'f8')]))

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 0 entries
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    0 non-null uint32
b    0 non-null object
c    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1), uint32(1)
memory usage: 76.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works.  However, perhaps not surprisingly, I noticed a huge speed difference in doing it this way (3.23 s to complete) compared to the earlier method above (168 ms) where the dataframe was created entirely of the same data type (float).  So in my case I think it's better to first fill the dataframe with floats then convert the desired columns to integers at the end.

Comment: To clarify: by speed difference, I mean the time it takes to fill the resulting dataframe with values using setter methods such as `df.at[] = ...`

Comment: @Bill there's nothing surprising here really, for homogeneous arrays pandas may use a single 2-D container as a backend.

Comment: @Bill You could also try just using raw numpy record array, and then convert it to a dataframe at the very end, this way it's zero-copy and could be faster even than the homogeneous dataframe approach.

Comment: Thanks @aldanor.  I realize now a dataframe wasn't the right approach for capturing this data.  I need to build the data in separate but fast and efficient data objects such as pandas.Series or numpy arrays and then combine them at the end into a data frame.

Comment: Can someone explain the syntax of this solution a bit?  It is not intuitive to me.  Thank you.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 this creates an empty numpy structured array with the desired dtype -- which pandas then uses to set dtypes of all columns in the dataframe.