# Initialize a Pandas DataFrame with a fill value other than NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I initialize an 'empty' DataFrame as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('AB'), columns=list('CD'))
```

The resulting `df` has the form

```
     C    D
A  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  NaN
```

Is there a pythonic way to replace the `NaN`s with some other value, say, `-np.inf`? Of course, one way to do it is simply to specify it as data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.ones((2,2))*(-np.inf), index=list('AB'), columns=list('CD'))
```

Perhaps there a more succinct way?

Comment: Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053329/elegant-way-to-create-empty-pandas-dataframe-with-nan-of-type-float](Elegant way to create empty pandas DataFrame with NaN of type float), you can initialize with `pd.DataFrame(data=...` whatever you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass scalar value as `data` param, this will set all elements to the same value:

```
In [181]:
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('AB'), columns=list('CD'), data=-np.inf)
df

Out[181]:
     C    D
A -inf -inf
B -inf -inf
```

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) show that `data` param can accept constants (scalar values) as well as array-like structures and dicts.