# What is the most efficient way of adding empty rows in an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 151 columns. I found out a [way](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/54184203.shtml) to add empty rows but for that I will have to write NaN 151 times.

Eventually I would want to be able to add three empty rows over the header row of the existing dataframe. With those empty rows I would use xlsxwriter to write some extra information and excel formulas.

Is there an efficient solution to this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might be in this: http://xyproblem.info/. What is it that you want to do?

Comment: edited my question..@ifly6

Comment: But why do you want to do that?

Comment: Will be using xlsxwriter to add some excel formulas and extra information in specific cells.

Comment: Make an empty dataframe as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053329/elegant-way-to-create-empty-pandas-dataframe-with-nan-of-type-float) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the two together

Comment: thanks so much! @G.Anderson