# Making an array of required dimension with 'nan' as remaining elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array A of just n elements. Making it (n x 1) .Is there a chance of making it (n x n) by putting all other elements as 'nan'. so that A.shape gives me (n,n) .

Comment: This question and its answers may be of assistance: [Initializing numpy matrix to something other than zero or one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704823/initializing-numpy-matrix-to-something-other-than-zero-or-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is any chance, that you could provide further information (such as what do you need it for), it would be great. Anyhow here is my solution:

```
import numpy as np 

#input array
example = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

#create a target matrix containing only 'nan' elements of size n*n
target = np.ones((len(example),len(example)))*float('nan')
#set first column to input array
target[0:,0] = example
```

result will be:

```
array([[  1.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  2.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  3.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  4.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  5.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```