# How to create a multidimensional matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a multidimensional matrix with numpy, to describe a RGB image. Something like this does not work:

numpy.full(100, 100, [0,0,0])

This fails with `TypeError: data type not understood`. What I'm trying to get at is a pixel matrix with rgb values at every pixel.

Edit: this gets me halfway there:

```
n = numpy.empty((3,3,3))
n[:] = [0,0,0]
```

However, this gives a float array for every point, while a uint8 array would suffice. How would I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing numpy matrix to something other than zero or one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704823/initializing-numpy-matrix-to-something-other-than-zero-or-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this does the trick:

```
n = numpy.empty((3,3,3))
n[:] = numpy.array([0,0,0], dtype=numpy.uint8)
```