# Perfplot raised a "TypeError: bench() got an unexpected keyword argument 'logx'". How to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, perfplot

After a search on SO for numpy array mixed dtype filling I found a nice little numpy array fill performance tester `perfplot`. When the posted [code answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45006691/8928024) from Nico Schlömer was ran, I saw a dip in the performance chart. So I changed the `perflot.show(..snippet..)` to `perflot.bench(..snippet..)` as suggest [here](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/#description) and got the following error:

> ```py
>   File "X:\ScriYpts\Z.py", line 40, in <module>
>     xlabel='length(a)'
> TypeError: bench() got an unexpected keyword argument 'logx'
> ```

How to fix?

My code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import perfplot


def fill(n):
    a = np.empty(n)
    a.fill(val)
    return a


def colon(n):
    a = np.empty(n)
    a[:] = val
    return a


def full(n):
    return np.full(n, val)


def ones_times(n):
    return val * np.ones(n)


def mlist(n):
    return np.array(n * [val])

val = 42.0


out = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: n,
    kernels=[fill, colon, full, ones_times, mlist],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(20)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='length(a)'
    )

out.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a dive into `perfplot main.py` I figured out there is no `logx'` and `logy` **kwargs available.

My solution:

```py
out = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: n,
    kernels=[fill, colon, full, ones_times, mlist],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(20)],
#    logx=True,  # disabled here
#    logy=True,  # disabled here
    xlabel='length(a)'
    )

out.show(logx=True, logy=True)  # both "log" **kwargs added here in `show()`
```

For some unknown reason `xlabel='length(a)'` is not accepted as **kwarg in `.show()` directly. And it works to leave it in `.bench()`.